# Add element to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

There are few topics regarding this, however, neither of them helped me in a way I need.

I would need to parse json by (some) fields that user enters, meaning the user can fill 3 out of 7 fields, leaving 4 empty. I cannot put attribute with an empty value to json, thus I need join only the entered ones.

This is where my issue comes, can't figure out the correct way to glue together, for example, *nw_src* with IP address (appearing as one variable) together with *nw_proto*, *dl_type* and potentially others, in the *match* attribute. In this code, Python expects comma instead of the colon between nw_proto and 1.

```
data2 = {}
data2['nw_src'] = '10.0.0.5' #or variable
json_data = json.dumps(data2)

data = {"dpid": "1", "priority": "65500", "table_id": "0", "match":
    {data2, 'nw_proto': '1', 'dl_type': '2048'}}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8080/stats/flowentry/add', data=json.dumps(data))
```

I tried this way, also with json_data and something like this:

```
data[0]['f'] = var
```

no one did the trick and resulted in error. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{data2, 'nw_proto': '1', 'dl_type': '2048'}` is not the right way of merging two dictionaries as one.

Assuming you are using Python 2.7, you can either use `dict` with unpacking the rest:

```
data = {..., "match": dict(data2, **{'nw_proto': '1', 'dl_type': '2048'})
```

or `.update()` before putting into the actual dict:

```
data2.update({'nw_proto': '1', 'dl_type': '2048'})
data = {..., "match": data2}
```